# R: Combine two elements of vector based on pattern

Tags: r

I would like to know how I could possibly add a function, like paste to combine to strings, which are characters, of a vector as one new element of a new vector:

So my problem would look like this:

a) My initial data stored as a txt file

```
10_x_R1_001.fastq.gz
10_x_R2_001.fastq.gz

11_x_R1_001.fastq.gz
11_x_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

This data I then have as a data vector, like

```
x= c("10_x_R1_001.fastq.gz", "10_x_R2_001.fastq.gz", "11_x_R1_001.fastq.gz", "11_x_R2_001.fastq.gz")
```

So my question would be, how can I add the elements with start/contain the indicator "10" or "11" as a new element so that the result would look like this.

```
x= c("10_x_R1_001.fastq.gz 10_x_R2_001.fastq.gz", "11_x_R1_001.fastq.gz 11_x_R2_001.fastq.gz")
```

Because the two elements are always nxt to each other I already solved the problem with rollapply of the *zoo* package, but I would like to know how I can do it otherwise.

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `base R` approach is to substring the first 2 characters, use that as grouping variable in `tapply` and `paste`

```
unname(tapply(x, substring(x, 1, 2), FUN = paste, collapse= ' '))
```

Or if the numbers can be different and have variable number of digits, then use `sub`

```
unname(tapply(x, sub("_.*", "", x), FUN = paste, collapse= " "))
#[1] "10_x_R1_001.fastq.gz 10_x_R2_001.fastq.gz" "11_x_R1_001.fastq.gz 11_x_R2_001.fastq.gz"
```

---

If the values are always next to each other, then use a logical recycling vector to extract alternate elements and `paste` together

```
paste(x[c(TRUE, FALSE)], x[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```